# How to add column name with text in R

Tags: r

I have a R data frame.Let's say my data,df_sample looks like below

```
var1  var2 var3 var4
12    22   32   42
23    11   22   32
25    15   12   11
```

I want to write a function which will take data frame name & variable name,not the index as per requirement, as input & will print a title.

so I tried this

```
    test <- function(data, var) {
      Title=paste("Check for:",var)
      message(Title)
    }
test(df_sample,var1)
```

But I'm getting error message as

```
Error in paste("Check for:",var) object 'var1' not found
```

can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: `test(df_sample,"var1")`, or perhaps you want to try [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)?

Comment: If you want to pass the name of the variable in without quotes, you'll need `substitute()` to turn it into an expression and then get it's string representation. It's much easier just to pass in a string though.

Comment: It's difficult for me to pass variable name with string like this `var1` as the data I shared is sample data actual data contains 100 columns. So I will use a for loop to get the column name & then store it in another variable & then I will pass that variable in test. I will try substitute()